# Is data sink phase take a lot of time during flink job execution?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I'm using VM and my cluster consists of 3 taskmanagers and the master is jobmanager and taskmanager too (4 taskmangers and one job manager) about 12 gb ram and 6 processors,and using flink-1.7.2 version but after I run a flink job

```
./bin/flink run -p 4 -q examples/gelly/flink-gelly-examples_*.jar --algorithm PageRank --input CSV --type integer --simplify directed --input_filename WikiTalk.txt --input_field_delimiter $'\t' --output print,
```

I found that the job is still running on the datasink(collect)

Comment: It depends on the size of the data set you have. Have you tried it with a larger dataset?

Comment: @chuckskull Wikitalk dataset, its size 66.5 MB

Comment: @chuckskull is the dataset so large to take more than one day

Comment: It seems very weird. Le me run on my PC.

Comment: Where did you download WikiTalk file?

Comment: @chuckskull from here https://snap.stanford.edu/data/wiki-Talk.html

Comment: It looks weird, but it could also be that the output size explodes (which shouldn't happen on PageRank).

Comment: @ArvidHeise , what did u mean about  the output size exploding?, and what should I do in this case or my problem?

Comment: In general for any kind of input dataset, the output could be much larger (depends on the algorithm and the inherent properties of the dataset). For example, consider an algorithm that returns the powerset of the input data. That's when the output "explodes". In that case, it's expected that output takes much longer. You can usually check that by using a sample of the input data.

Comment: @ArvidHeise, OK, I will try a sample and see the result, could u check my command line if it has something wrong?

Comment: The trailing comma looks suspicious, but I have not worked with gelly yet.